# Write $\sin^2(\arctan x)$ as an algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Write the expression $\sin^2(\arctan x)$ as an algebraic expression.

I have done many similar problems to this and am coherent in double angle formulas for similar questions as well. My issue lies with the squared sine equation. How am I supposed to go about this?  Do I simply square the algebraic expression I get from $\arctan x$? For example sine is the ratio *Opposite/Hypotenuse*, so $(x/\sqrt{x^2+1})$ would be squared, and I would get $\sin^2(\arctan x) = (x^2)/(x^2+1)$?

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$\frac{\sin^2(\arctan(x))}{\cos^2(\arctan(x))} = \tan^2(\arctan(x))=x^2$$
i.e.
$$\frac{\sin^2(\arctan(x))}{1-\sin^2(\arctan(x))} = x^2$$

i.e.
$$\sin^2(\arctan(x)) = x^2(1-\sin^2(\arctan(x)))$$

i.e.
$$\sin^2(\arctan(x))\times(1+x^2) = x^2$$

i.e.
$$\sin^2(\arctan(x)) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes; below is the entire thought process.

Suppose $y=\arctan x$.  Then $x=\tan y$ and we have $\sin y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.  Thus, it follows that $$\sin^2(\arctan x)=(\sin y)^2=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$ as you suspected.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta=1-{1\over\sec^2\theta}=1-{1\over1+\tan^2\theta}={\tan^2\theta\over1+\tan^2\theta}$$

Therefore

$$\sin^2(\arctan x)={\tan^2(\arctan x)\over1+\tan^2(\arctan x)}={x^2\over1+x^2}$$